# Directory Structure Yesod and Stack

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I have a simple Yesod project with the usual directory structure like this:

```
./Main.hs
./Foundation.hs
./Handler/Home.hs
./Handler/... etc
./config/routes
./templates/home.hamlet
./templates/default-layout.hamlet
./templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet
./templates/default-layout-wrapper.cassius
...
```

I am trying to build this project with stack, where typically the `Main.hs` program is under the `app` directory.

I have tried to place all the Yesod structure under the `app` dir (the `app` dir is the `.` above).

the project's cabal file looks like this:

```
executable proj-web01-exe
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base, bytestring, split, filepath
                     , stm, data-default, text, conduit, conduit-extra
                     , containers, resourcet, blaze-html, blaze-markup
                     , shakespeare, yesod, yesod-static
                     , proj-web01
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Now when I try to `stack build`, I get the following error message :

```
[1 of 6] Compiling Foundation       ( app/Foundation.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/proj-web01-exe/proj-web01-exe-tmp/Foundation.o )

/home/me/proj-web01/app/Foundation.hs:46:35:
    Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
      Called widgetFileNoReload on "default-layout", but no templates were found.
    Code: widgetFileNoReload (def) "default-layout"
    In the splice: $(widgetFileNoReload def "default-layout")

--  While building package proj-web01-0.1.0.0 using:
      /home/me/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0 build lib:proj-web01 exe:proj-web01-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

`widgetFileNoReload` does not know where to find the "default-layout" files, which are in the `app/templates` directory.

**My question :** should I write the cabal file differently, or should I place the templates, Handler... folders elsewhere (eg in src)? What is the most natural directory structure when using stack? Or alternatively how to set up stack parameters (cabal and yaml files) to fit a usual Yesod directory structure?

Answer (score 1):

If you take the standard Yesod scaffolding, it should compile without issue with Stack (I am actually doing that right now, as a matter of fact). I'd recommend against moving the scaffolded files around until you're familiar with the setup. If you really want to move the source files, I'd recommend keeping the templates in the original location.